# Sql stored prcedure take's more time to execute whn records are getting increased is there any way to optimize it

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

[image]I have 6,00,000 records and i want to fetch 10 records from them as i want to display only 10 records in the grid my stored procedure is working properly when i m fetching records between 1-10000 E.G (500-510) after that the execution time is increased when the row number is increased E.G if i fetch record b/w  1,00,000-1,00,010 it takes more time to execute

can any one please help me i have used ROW_NUMBER() to get the number row number and used between to retrieve data.

please give a optimized way to get records

The stored procedure creats a sql query as given below

I have 6,00,000 records and i want to fetch 10 records from them as i want to display only 10 records in the grid my stored procedure is working properly when i m fetching records between 1-10000 E.G (500-510) after that the execution time is increased when the row number is increased E.G if i fetch record b/w  1,00,000-1,00,010 it takes more time to execute

can any one please help me i have used ROW_NUMBER() to get the number row number and used between to retrieve data.

please give a optimized way to get records

The stored procedure create a sql query as given below

```
    SELECT FuelClaimId from  

     (  SELECT fc.FuelClaimId,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by fc.FuelClaimId ) AS RowNum  
    from   FuelClaims fc   

      INNER JOIN Vehicles v on fc.VehicleId =v.VehicleId     

        INNER JOIN Drivers d on d.DriverId =v.OfficialID  

        INNER JOIN Departments de on de.DepartmentId =d.DepartmentId   

        INNER JOIN Provinces p on de.ProvinceId =p.ProvinceId  

        INNER JOIN FuelRates f on f.FuelRateId =fc.FuelRateId   

        INNER JOIN FuelClaimStatuses fs on fs.FuelClaimStatusId= fc.statusid

        INNER JOIN LogsheetMonths  l on l.LogsheetMonthId  =f.LogsheetMonthId

        Where fc.IsDeleted = 0) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 
    600000 And 600010
```

Comment: you should give the your procedure definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT TOP 10 fc.FuelClaimId
FROM FuelClaims fc
    INNER JOIN Vehicles v ON fc.VehicleId = v.VehicleId     
    INNER JOIN Drivers d ON d.DriverId = v.OfficialID  
    INNER JOIN Departments de ON de.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId   
    INNER JOIN Provinces p ON de.ProvinceId = p.ProvinceId  
    INNER JOIN FuelRates f ON f.FuelRateId = fc.FuelRateId   
    INNER JOIN FuelClaimStatuses fs ON fs.FuelClaimStatusId = fc.statusid
    INNER JOIN LogsheetMonths  l ON l.LogsheetMonthId = f.LogsheetMonthId
WHERE fc.IsDeleted = 0 AND fc.FuelClaimId BETWEEN 600001 AND 600010 
ORDER BY fc.FuelClaimId
```

Also BETWEEN is inclusive so BETWEEN 10 and 20 actually returns 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 and 20 so 11 rows not 10. As identity values usually start at 1 you really want `BETWEEN 11 AND 20` (hence 600001 in the above)

The above query should fix your issue where your performance degrades as you query the larger range of items.

While it won't always return 10 records the fix for that is:

```
WHERE fc.IsDeleted = 0 AND fc.FuelClaimId > @LastMaxFuelClaimId
```

Where `@LastMaxFuelClaimId` is the previous MAX FuelClaimId you had returned from the previous query execution.

Edit: The reason why it keeps getting slower is because it has to read more and more of the table to read the next chunk, it doesn't skip reading the first 600,000 records it reads them all and then only returns the next 10 hence each time you query it reads all the previous records all over again, the above does not suffer from the same problem.

Comment: This would work if `FuelClaimId`'s are contiguous but that might not be the case.

Comment: @Lieven I noticed that after i wrote it, I have updated my answer with a solution which will work when `FuelClaimId` is not contiguous.

Comment: +1 Definitly a better performing solution than (ab)using rownumbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should post an execution plan but a probable cause of performance problems would be inadequate or lack of indexing.

**Make sure you have**

- an index on all your foreign key relations
- a covering index on the fields you retrieve and select from

**Covering Index**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_FUELCLAIMS_FUELCLAIMID_ISDELETED 
  ON dbo.FuelClaims (FuelClaimId, VehicleID, IsDeleted)
```

Comment: I have used all the foreign key as primary key so index is created automatically on the primary key ....

Comment: @Smith.Patel - True but not automatically on the `foreign key`. Can you also post an execution plan?

Comment: @Smith.Patel - Can you add the covering index, try again and post the new execution plan?